# Will Allah forgive me for this bad dua?

Tags: allah, dua, forgiveness

i did a bad dua and i said "Allah dont forgive me even if i felt regret about doing this dua".i felt regret and sadness about asking this dua so i repented.Will allah still forgive me or no?

Comment: Deleting this question after you got an answer is incredibly disrespectful for the user who put in the time and effort to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaikum

Firstly, we should be careful about which duas we ask before we ask them. Asking for something haraam is not answered by Allah anyway as He wouldn't answer an haraam dua.

The fact that you repented is the correct start though. Allah knows what is in the hearts of everyone. He knows what we don't know and His mercy encompasses all things. He knows also that we are human and that we can falter. So never give up on His mercy. Whenever we commit a sin we should meet 4 conditions for our sin to be forgiven, this is any sin committed between you and Allah which doesn't involve another human being:

1. admit your sin
2. regret your sin
3. ask Allah to forgive you for that sin
4. promise not to do the sin again whilst doing everything possible to stay away from that sin, even if it means breaking up with certain evil company of people, stop watching certain things on TV, giving up certain habits etc which may have lead to that sin in the first place.

Thereafter if we were to commit that same sin again, even a hundred times, due to our human weakness and the shaitaan's temptations being too much for us, if we were to meet those same 4 conditions again there is absolutely no reason why Allah wouldn't forgive us so long as we don't associate partners with Him in worship of course and so long as it really is due to human weakness (Allah knows). This is the condition for sins committed not involving anyone else.

However in the case of the sin involving one of Allah's creatures (or another human being) then you must first ask that person to forgive you as it's their right above yours. If they forgive you that's great. However if they don't then they gain some of your good deeds on the Day of Reckoning. This applies to everyone you wrong until eventually you have no good deeds left. This would also be the case of those doing wrong to you of course (you get their good deeds). But it is best for one to forgive as Allah loves forgiveness.

If Allah has forgiven your sin but you still keep feeling regret and seeking forgiveness for it, it then causes your status to rise so the more someone repents to Allah, the better it is for that person

4 conditions of repentance- Mufti Menk https://youtu.be/DS39foiWhr4

Jundab reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “A man said: By Allah, Allah will not forgive this person! Allah Almighty said: Who is he who swore by me that I will not forgive someone? I have forgiven him and nullified your good deeds.” Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 2621

Say: O my servants! who have acted extravagantly against their own souls, do not despair of the mercy of Allah; surely Allah forgives the faults altogether; surely, He is the Forgiving the Merciful. (Az-Zumar 39:53).

Then hasten on from the Place from which the people hasten on and ask the forgiveness of Allah; surely Allah is Forgiving, Merciful. (Al-Baqarah 2:199).

Surely Allah does not forgive that anything should be associated with Him, and He forgives what is besides this to whom He pleases; and whoever associates anything with Allah, he indeed strays off into a remote error. (An-Nisaa’ 4:116).

Surely Allah does not forgive that anything should be associated with Him, and forgives what is besides that to whomsoever He pleases; and whoever associates anything with Allah, he devises indeed a great sin. (An-Nisaa’ 4:48).

This link may also help: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/5113/why-doesnt-allaah-answer-our-duaas

I hope this answers your question, in shaa Allah and Allah knows best.

Salaams

EDIT: please everyone who finds my answer helpful upvote me. JzK